# How to wait for result of speech recognition in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, speech-recognition, android-speech-api

I am using recognition listener for speech recognition in android. The basic construct of my class is as follows:

```
class SpeechInput implements RecognitionListener {

    Intent intent;
    SpeechRecognizer sr;
    boolean stop;

    public void init() {
        sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
        sr.setRecognitionListener(this);
        intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,3);
    }

    ...

}
```

I am stuck in a situation where I want to run android recognition listener in a loop, something over the lines of:

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
       // Some processing code
       sr.startListening(intent);
}
```

Now, I want to wait for the output before it starts listening again. In order to achieve this, I tried to use locking mechanism as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
       // Some processing code
       sr.startListening(intent);
       stop = false; 
       new Task().execute().get();
}
```

where Task is an asyncTask defined as follows:

```
private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            int counter = 0;
            while(!stop) {
                counter++;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The boolean value 'stop' is updated in the 'onResults' method of RecognitionListener as follows:

```
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ...
    stop = true;
}
```

The problem is that speech recognition is not working at all. Nothing is happening, it is not even starting. I guess this is because the asyncTask is taking up all the processor time. Can you please guide me towards an architecture where I would be able to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart the listening when you receive a result. No loop needed, no waiting needed.

I'm not an expert on Speech recognition on Android but you are probably blocking the Main thread with the call

```
new Task().execute().get();
```

So the speech recognition is probably never started.

Comment: Thanks mate. Solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to note that the methods of Speech Recognition API of Android **can only be invoked from the main thread** and all the callbacks are executed on the main thread of the application.

As a result, when the main thread gets blocked, the recognition listener also gets blocked which is why nothing happens when I try to execute speech recognition the way shown in the question.

Taking a cue from accepted answer, I used the `onResults` method of `RecognitionListener` interface to restart the listener as shown below:

```
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ...
    sr.startListening(intent);
}
```